# Assign values to a variable from a Angular subscriber

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-observables

I am very new to Angular. I have done the services and the templates, I am starting to do the components. I am trying to assign a list of values (templates) from a rest service. If the user is admin, he can see all of them, and it works that part. If the user is not an administrator, he can only see his own, but I can't get the subscriber to store the user's profile.
When I try to assign it it doesn't do it. I've read that it's because subscribers are asynchronous methods, but I can't really find a solution. How could I assign the values from the server to the variable so I can render it in the view?

**Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-plantilla',
  templateUrl: './plantilla.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class PlantillaComponent implements OnInit {

  public titulo = 'Colección de plantillas';
  public plantillas: Plantilla[] = [];
  public perfil: Perfil = new Perfil();

  constructor(private plantillaServicio: PlantillaService, private authService: AuthService, private perfilServicio: PerfilService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {

      console.log(this.authService.usuario);
      if (this.authService.usuario.rol.id===1 ) {
        console.log("al if");
//this works
        this.plantillaServicio.listar().subscribe(plantillas =>
          this.plantillas = plantillas);
      }else{
        console.log("al else");
//this works
        console.log(this.perfilServicio.ver(this.authService.usuario.id).subscribe(val => console.log(val)));
//this doesn't work
        this.perfilServicio.ver(this.authService.usuario.id).subscribe((val:Perfil)=>this.perfil=val);
//show empty class
        console.log(this.perfil);
      }

    } else {
      console.log("No autenticado");
    }
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<div
    class="card container"
    *ngFor="let plantilla of plantillas"
>
    <div class="row g-0">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3 class="card-title">
                {{plantilla.id}} - {{plantilla.empresa.nombre}} - {{plantilla.empresa.id}}
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- <div class="card-header">{{plantilla.asunto}}</div> -->
            <div class="card-body text-dark bg-light mb-3">
                <h5 class="card-title">{{plantilla.asunto}}</h5>
                <p
                    class="card-text"
                    [innerHTML]=plantilla.texto
                ></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried in the `*ngIf="plantillas?.length>0"` view but the console shows that templates can be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is this:

The key was to understand, as James said, asynchronism. While the subscriber is being performed, and it may take a little or a lot of time, but it takes time anyway, the next instruction is performed. If that instruction depends on the result of the subscriber, it will not work as expected.

It should be noted that each subscriber has three parameters, the event, the error and the completion. Within the completion block, the rest of the instructions can be performed, but always within this block, not outside it or the subscriber. To do this, I have required one more subscriber, a chained one.
The first subscriber retrieves the profile, the second one retrieves the plantillas, which is what I really want. And the view code I haven't had to touch it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-plantilla',
  templateUrl: './plantilla.component.html'
})
export class PlantillaComponent implements OnInit {

  public titulo = 'Colección de plantillas';
  public plantillas: Plantilla[] = [];
  public perfil: Perfil = new Perfil();
  private empresa: Empresa = new Empresa ();

  constructor(private plantillaServicio: PlantillaService,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private perfilServicio: PerfilService,
    private empresaServicio: EmpresaService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {

      console.log(this.authService.usuario);
      if (this.authService.usuario.rol.id === 1) {
        console.log("al if");
        this.plantillaServicio.listar().subscribe(plantillas => this.plantillas = plantillas);
      } else {
        console.log("al else");
//call to old suscriptor
        this.setPerfil(this.authService.usuario.id);
      }
    } else {
      console.log("No autenticado");
    }
  }

// old suscriptor but modified
  setPerfil(id: number): void {
    this.perfilServicio.ver(this.authService.usuario.id)
      .subscribe((val: Perfil) => {
        this.perfil = val;
        console.log(val);
      }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }, () => {
        console.log('perfil complete!');
//call to new suscriptor
        this.setPlantillas(this.perfil.id);
      });
  }

//new suscriptor
  setPlantillas(id: number): void {
    this.plantillaServicio.listarPorEmpresa(id)
    .subscribe((val: Plantilla[]) => {
      this.plantillas=val;
      console.log(val);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    }, () => {
      console.log('plantillas complete!');
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem when people learn Rxjs for the first time.

> console.log(this.perfilServicio.ver(this.authService.usuario.id).subscribe(val => console.log(val)));

Your outer console log which wraps the whole statement will only ever log out the subscription. *Not* the result of the subscription. The inner console log will log the value of the result, since it is inside your `subscribe` block and completes async.

> this.perfilServicio.ver(this.authService.usuario.id).subscribe((val:Perfil)=>this.perfil=val);
> //show empty class
> console.log(this.perfil);

Your console log at the bottom here will execute *before* you have set the variable inside your subscribe block.

```
this.perfilServicio.ver(this.authService.usuario.id)
    .subscribe((val:Perfil)=>{
        this.perfil=val;
        console.log(this.perfil); //This will now work
    });
```

I would highly recommend learning the basics of subscriptions and observables. https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/concepts/rxjs-primer

The reason your templates can be undefined is because they'll render before your observables complete. Therefore you need to be aware of this by wrapping any async code inside (e.g.) an `*ngIf="!asyncVariable"`.

Or you could utilise angular async templates like the following

Your html would use an async pipe https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

```html
*ngFor="let plantilla of plantillas | async"
```

Your ts file would not subscribe to the observable. It would just assign it. The subscription happens under the hood with angular async pipe.

```
this.plantillas = this.plantillaServicio.listar();
```

Comment: Thanks James, I have been reading through the documentation you have pointed me to. I like the one in the first link better, but none of them have been helpful in solving my problem. Although I think you've got it right about printing before the variable is full, at least that's how it appears in the browser console, out of order. Neither does the async pipe, which throws a large list of errors.

Comment: What does it show? And what code did you try?